# Analytics GA4 multiples filter on report

Tags: google-analytics, report

I have a problem with the filters at the level of Google Analytics which do not work, I explain myself, I try to put two filters on my report, the first is that all the pages with the name "menu-droite" must be excluded in addition to the homepage /home/

I manage to put the first filter on the name "menu-droite" but then when I want to select the second variable for the pages, I have nothing :

[second filter page didn't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQRT1.png)

I can do this another way by selecting all the pages to exclude which brings me back to a single filter but I would have to select some 100 pages and new pages under "menu-droite" are often published which won't change anything to problems

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with reports. Its very limited on how to craft filtering for them.  What you want to do instead is dive into Explore, and craft custom Segments to better manage your data.